# Label name from array value VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a array containing up to 10 values. 
I have 10 labels (label1, label2 ... so on to 10)
I wantto use the array value to get a label.
How do i get "label(arrayvalue).visiable = true

Im thinking about something like this

```
    bokstavValue = Array.IndexOf(bokstav, TextBox1.Text)
    label(bokstavValue).Visible= True
```

Comment: visual studio with windows form

Comment: This is not VBA... This is VB.Net

Comment: My mistake. Changed tag

Comment: Change your title please, too. Its missleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more along the lines of `Me.Controls("labelName").Visible` as long as it is not embedded in a groupbox or panel or tab. That woulb be to change the actual control on the form

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if VBA, but for getting an array value, you have to give the index of the value you want, like:

```
aArray = Array(1,2,3,4) ''Returns a single dimension array of 4 elements, from index 0 to 3
Value = aArray (1) ''Returns 2
```

So, if you want to modify the visibility of a Label, calling it by its name, you can use:

```
aArray = Array("Label1","Label2") ''Returns a single dimension array of 2 elements, from index 0 to 1
Label(aArray(0)).Visible = True ''Turns on label "Label1"
Label(aArray(1)).Visible = True ''Turns on label "Label2"
```